# Rally: Split unfinished story via web service

Tags: rally

Is there any way in the Rally web service to perform the Split action on a user story?

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly be possible to write a web services script that would accomplish a Split of unfinished stories between Sprints. That said, to replicate the functionality of the Story Splitter in the Rally UI, described in detail here:

`http://www.rallydev.com/help/manage-unfinished-work#split user stories`

There are a number of choices presented to the user in terms of what is the target Iteration, which Tasks to move, updates to the Schedule State and Plan Estimate Fields, etc.

It would be a good idea to visit with Scrum leaders as to the appropriate working agreements around auto-assigning values where the user would otherwise be making choices in the UI, to ensure consistent behavior amongst your teams.